# Twilio create address subaccount issue api php

Tags: php, rest, api, twilio

I have a little problem with my code! I'm trying to create an address for a subaccount in twilio (in order to buy some number where an address are required).

My code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require __DIR__ . '/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "xxxxx";
$token = "xxxx";
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$address = $client->addresses->create(
    array(
        "CustomerName" => "Customer",
        "Street" => "2 rue du chapelier ",
        "City" => "",         
        "Region" => "France",
        "PostalCode" => "75020",
        "IsoCountry" => "FR",
    )
 );

 ?>
```

And I have in return this error

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\AddressList::create(), called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/taddresses.php on line 26 and defined in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/AddressList.php on line 49
>
> Warning: Missing argument 3 for Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\AddressList::create(), called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/taddresses.php on line 26 and defined in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/AddressList.php on line 49
>
> Warning: Missing argument 4 for Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\AddressList::create(), called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/taddresses.php on line 26 and defined in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/AddressList.php on line 49
>
> Warning: Missing argument 5 for Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\AddressList::create(), called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/taddresses.php on line 26 and defined in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/AddressList.php on line 49
>
> Warning: Missing argument 6 for Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\AddressList::create(), called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/taddresses.php on line 26 and defined in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/AddressList.php on line 49
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: street in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/AddressList.php on line 54
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: city in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/AddressList.php on line 55
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: region in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/AddressList.php on line 56
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: postalCode in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/AddressList.php on line 57
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: isoCountry in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/AddressList.php on line 58
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twilio\Exceptions\RestException' with message '[HTTP 400] Unable to create record: IsoCountry must be provided' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Version.php:85 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Version.php(207): Twilio\Version->exception(Object(Twilio\Http\Response), 'Unable to creat...') #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/AddressList.php(68): Twilio\Version->create('POST', '/Accounts/AC545...', Array, Array) #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/taddresses.php(26): Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\AddressList->create(Array) #3 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Version.php on line 85

I use the twilio php api. Im able to create subaccount, search new number, buy number etc etc but for addresses im stuck!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not sure whether you're using version 4 or version 5 of the [Twilio PHP helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php) but either way you're providing the arguments incorrectly. You shouldn't be providing an array of arguments, instead they should be provided as positional arguments. See the [version 4](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/4.12.0/Services/Twilio/Rest/Addresses.php#L11) and [version 5](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/5.5.0/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/AddressList.php#L49) source code.

So your code should look like:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require __DIR__ . '/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "xxxxx";
$token = "xxxx";
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$address = $client->addresses->create(
    "Customer", "2 rue du chapelier ", "", "France", "75020", "FR"
  )
);

?>
```

Let me know if that helps.